# Flatten nested data in Big Query to a single row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[This is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRq4i.png)

[image]

[This is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P48oi.png)

[image]

I just need the flattened data to show destination 1 and destination 2 as well as duration 1 and duration 2.

I have used the unnest function in Big Query but it creates multiple rows. I am unable to use any aggregation to group the multiple rows as the data is non-numeric. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT EnquiryReference, 
  Destinations[OFFSET(0)].Name AS Destination1,
  Destinations[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].Name AS Destination2,
  Destinations[OFFSET(0)].Duration AS Duration1,
  Destinations[SAFE_OFFSET(1)].Duration AS Duration2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question

[image]

result will be

[image]

Comment: @ChinduSahidtiaSadason - glad it helped. Consider also voting up the answer